# click not working on searchitem from listview android

Tags: android, listview

Click on search item inside edittext redirect on wrong activity, it doesn't open the activity associated with it. It opening other activities that are associated with other listitems but not that i am clicking one.

**Here is my complete code:**

```
public class Tabtwo extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    ListView listView;
    TextView txt;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText edtSearch;

    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] { "Admin Cost", "Affinity Diagram",
            "Analyse", "Apprasal Costs", "Assessment of Stakeholders",
              };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[] { R.drawable.admin, R.drawable.affinity,
            R.drawable.analysis, R.drawable.appraisal, R.drawable.assessment,
              };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabtwo);

        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("txt", countries[i]);

            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]));
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag", "txt" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag, R.id.txt };

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        edtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Search_box);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Admincost.class);
            startActivity(int0);
        }

        if (position == 1) {
            Intent int1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Affinity.class);
            startActivity(int1);
        }
        if (position == 2) {
            Intent int2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Analyse.class);
            startActivity(int2);
        }

        if (position == 3) {
            Intent int3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ApprasalCosts.class);
            startActivity(int3);
        }
        if (position == 4) {
            Intent int1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Assessment.class);
            startActivity(int1);
        } }
    }
}
```

Here is my tabtwo xml file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Search_box"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Search a Item from ListView"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/List_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is listview_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="21dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you have a custom adapter?

Comment: @niteshgoel `final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);` find this line in code. read the question carefully.

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar first show your custom adapter. as well as XML file of that adapter `R.layout.listview_layout`.

Comment: As you have assigned associated activities to be opened, position wise, whenever  you'll perform filtration,  your particular items in list view will loose their previous position and will be assigned new positions. try some other way to assign activities to your items.

Comment: Hey you have defined two adapters one in class level and other within the method , resolve it to one and remove the useless

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar not this XML file i want `listview_layout.xml`

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar instead of asking code. first show that xml file so we can get to know what you had done.

Comment: @Silentkillor, I have pasted all code here.

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar Did you try my answer.. It should work.. I tried and it meets your requirement without any flaw..

Comment: @Tamilan, I am trying. pls wait

Comment: Thnks to all for such a valuable replies......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your onItemClick method with below and try.. Hope it works..

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {

        TextView tv = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        String str = tv.getText().toString().trim();

        if (str.equals(countries[0])) {
            Intent int0 = new Intent(Tabtwo.this, Admincost.class);
            startActivity(int0);
        }else if(str.equals(countries[1])) {
            Intent int1 = new Intent(Tabtwo.this, Affinity.class);
            startActivity(int1);
        }else if(str.equals(countries[2])) {
            Intent int2 = new Intent(Tabtwo.this, Analyse.class);
            startActivity(int2);
        }else if(str.equals(countries[3])) {
            Intent int3 = new Intent(Tabtwo.this, ApprasalCosts.class);
            startActivity(int3);
        }else if(str.equals(countries[4])) {
            Intent int1 = new Intent(Tabtwo.this, Assessment.class);
            startActivity(int1);
        } 
}
```

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar did you try my answer.. It should work.. i tried and it meets your requirement without any flaw..

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your `TextView` as well as to `ImageView`

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

and for ItemClick you can use the answer of **Tamilan**

Comment: Its not working friend, On each click it is taking to me at first activity or other useless one.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same question with you. Try the following one:

```
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                            //(String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
                             String city_id=map.get( (String) adapter.getItem(position) );
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),city_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("city_id",city_id);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }               
                    });
```